# How can I exclude a string if it ends in ".d.ts"?

Tags: regex, gulp, glob

I am using regex type glob to include files in gulp. How can I use a regex to ignore strings that end with a ".d.ts" but include all others?

Already I have this:

```
"app/*.*"
```

but it's including filenames with any ending.

Is there a way I can limit it to just those not ending in .d.ts? So for example these would be okay:

```
app/abc.html
app/abc.js
app/abc.ts
```

But this would not

```
app/abc.d.ts
```

Comment: you mean this https://regex101.com/r/aM3eJ0/1 . but it's a regex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I ignore a file using gulp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818193/how-do-i-ignore-a-file-using-gulp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.*(?<!\.d\.ts)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LtGX4aAwVEBi-wOk)

(assuming lookbehind assertions are supported by your regex flavor. I dont know "gulp")

Comment: [gulp uses glob](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md), not regex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Comment: The QA asked for a regex, so I gave him one.

Answer (score 5):

In your `src` definition, you can use bang (`!`) to exclude paths, like:

```
gulp.src(['path/to/src/**/*.*', '!path/to/src/**/*.d.ts'])
```

[The minimatch documentation discusses the bang syntax.](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch#comparisons-to-other-fnmatchglob-implementations)

Just noticed this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818193) has additional details.